# Stop accessing all values in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to edit a particular todo rendered in a `v-for`. But all of my `todo`s go into edit mode at the same time. I am new to Vue.

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>All Todos</h1>
    <div v-for="todo in todos">
        <h4 v-if="editTodo===false">{{ todo.content }} <span class="label label-primary" @click="editTodoFun(todo)">Edit</span></h4>
        <div v-if="editTodo===true">
           <input type="text" v-model="editTodoVal" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>
    export default {
    data () {
        return {
            editTodo: false
        }
        },
    computed: {
    todos() {
        return this.$store.getters.getAllTodoDetails;
    }
    },
    methods: {
       editTodoFun(x) {
           this.editTodo = true;
       }
    }
    }
</script>
```

---

When I click on edit, editTodo becomes true for all items. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add an `editing` property to your todo objects.

Then you can use

```
v-if="todo.editing"
```

Instead of your global `editTodo`.

```
<div v-for="todo in todos">
    <h4 v-if="!todo.editing">{{ todo.content }} <span class="label label-primary" @click="todo.editing = true">Edit</span></h4>
    <div v-if="todo.editing">
       <input type="text" v-model="todo.content">
       <span class="label label-success" @click="todo.editing = false">Edit</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a slightly modified version as an example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [{
          content: "Learn Vue",
          editing: false
        },
        {
          content: "Learn JavaScript",
          editing: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>All Todos</h1>
  <div v-for="todo in todos">
    <h4 v-if="!todo.editing">{{ todo.content }} <button class="label label-primary" @click="todo.editing = true">Edit</button></h4>
    <div v-if="todo.editing">
      <input type="text" v-model="todo.content">
      <button class="label label-success" @click="todo.editing = false">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @StraightEdge You're welcome :) As a new user, don't forget to accept an answer if/when it solves your problem (and/or upvote when you have the privilege to do so).